# Injection of autowired dependencies failed, org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I upgraded spring libraries to 3.2.9 for java 8 upgrade. I am getting the following error. Any pointers will be appreciated

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'acsManagerImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private net.taxstream.acs.repository.LdapDAO net.taxstream.acs.service.AcsManagerImpl.ldapDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ldapDao' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/caa-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ldapTemplate' while setting bean property 'ldapTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ldapTemplate' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/caa-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'contextSource' while setting bean property 'contextSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'contextSource' is defined
```

This is the AcsManagerImpl:

```
@Service
public class AcsManagerImpl implements AcsManager {

    @Autowired
    private AcsRepository acsRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    private LdapDAO ldapDao;

    /**
     * @param acsRepository the acsRepository to set
     */
    public void setAcsRepository(AcsRepository acsRepository) {
        this.acsRepository = acsRepository;
    }

    public <T extends Serializable> Page<T> getComponent(Class<T> type, Pageable pageable) {
        return acsRepository.getComponent(type, pageable);
    }

}
```

This is the LDAPDAO:

```
public interface LdapDAO<E> {

    List<E> getUserInfo(final String uid);

    List<E> searchUsers(final String uid);

    void setFilter(final String filter);

    void setAttributes(final String[] attrs);
}
```

This is the CAAservlet code snippet

```
<bean id="ldapTemplate" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate" 
       p:contextSource-ref="contextSource" 
       p:ignorePartialResultException="true" 
    />
    
    <bean id="ldapDao" class="net.acs.repository.LdapDaoImpl"> 
       <property name="ldapTemplate" ref="ldapTemplate" /> 
       <property name="filter" value="(uid=@)" />
       <property name="attributes">
           <list>
               <value>cn</value>
               <value>mail</value>
               <value>uid</value>
               <value>givenname</value>
               <value>sn</value>
           </list>
       </property> 
   </bean>
```

Context source is defined in application context.xml:

```
 <bean id="contextSource" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource">
       
       <property name="url" value="ldap://C5QSQ13:10389/" />
       <property name="base" value="ou=people,o=sevenSeas" />
        <property name="anonymousReadOnly" value="true" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: Did you read the entire error message?

Comment: Context source is defined in application context file. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing a contextSource. Its in the full error message.

```
No bean named 'contextSource' is defined
```

**Example:**

```
<ldap:context-source
    username="cn=Administrator"
    password="secret"
    url="ldap://localhost:389" />
```

Some more info -> https://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/current/reference/#code-contextsource-code-configuration

Comment: Context source is defined in application context file. I updated the question

Comment: @redds1 Is that the same place you defined the ldapTemplate bean?